# localhost doesn't point to 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost, hosts

when I `ping localhost`, the answer is:

```
alsotang@alsotang-laptop:~$ ping localhost
PING localhost (61.139.8.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

but the `hosts` file has a record that `127.0.0.1<feff> localhost`

How can I fix it??

ps: my system is Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What's the result of `nslookup localhost` ?

Comment: Server:  61.139.2.69
Address: 61.139.2.69#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: localhost
Address: 61.139.8.100

Comment: solve it, thank u. By the way....I'm chinese....Now in SiChuan Univ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your host file.

```
    127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Do the following:

```
    Go to ->windows->system32->etc->host
    remove-> ::1 localhost
    set-> 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: forgive me..I forget to said that my system is Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Anyway, thx your answer. My /etc/hosts used to has the record `127.0.0.1<feff> localhost`, when I remove `<feff>` from it, the localhost point to 127.0.0.1 again.

Comment: For Windows 10 the correct path is: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 2):

If someone has made a mistake with your DNS server, that might cause an issue. Try `nslookup localhost`. If there is a DNS server entry for localhost (other than 127.0.0.1), contact the server admin.

Answer (score 1):

On linux and max platforms, ensure that your hosts file has content like this. You can try a editor restart, or system restart.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

This is a DNS issue. For additional help, you can refer the following resources

1. [Virtual Host](https://vitux.com/linux-hosts-file/)
2. [windows specific](https://gist.github.com/zenorocha/18b10a14b2deb214dc4ce43a2d2e2992)
3. [Blog on DNS](https://blog.catchpoint.com/2014/07/01/dns-lookup-domain-name-ip-address/)